# MySQL find date range with count

Tags: mysql, analytics

In MySQL, it is fairly easy to find the number of records that exist within some time interval.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE create_date > '2018-01-01 01:15:00' AND create_date < '2018-01-01 02:15:00'
```

But I want to do the opposite, sort of. Rather than providing a time interval and getting a count of records, I want to provide a count of records and check if a X minute time interval exists where more than Y many records were created. Getting the exact time interval is not essential, only if one exists or not. At a higher level, I am attempting to identify if there was any X minute "surge" when more than Y records where created during the course of a day.

For example, in the past 24 hours was there any 1 hour interval where a "surge" of more than 50 new records occurred?

I have already ruled out dividing the 24 hours into blocks of 1 hour intervals and checking each block. This does not work because the "surge" could span two sequential 1 hour blocks, such as 25 records at the end of the 01:00:00 block and 25 records at the beginning of the 02:00:00 block.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM records r1 
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records r2 
    WHERE ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r1.create_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r2.create_date)) < X) > Y
```

What this does is count how many records have more than `Y` records that have been created within `X` seconds after or before each record.

So basically it will return >=1 if there are any, 0 if not.

Comment: You're not anchoring the count to the time though, so they have no way of knowing when that surge starts. Also, you will have a ton of surges. So now, 30 seconds from now, 5 seconds from then. statistically this is super taxing, which is why this operation is performed after the fact on logged data 1-time and not in real time with a query on most analytics engines.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Correct. However, the OP stated that the exact time is not necessary.

Comment: All you give them is a count though? All this tells them is that at some time a surge happened.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. The only problem is the count is not enforcing all the records to be consecutive. That is, if I run this on 24 hours of data with a threshold of 50, it will return "true" if it finds 5 separate groups of 10 records spread across the 24 hours. Really all 50 records need to be part of the same group to meet the threshold.

Comment: @worpet that's what I thought too at first, but then again, the query wont return >0 if there are no records having more than 50 consecutive records in range, because it looks at each record individually and compares all others against it. I could be wrong, its really hard to wrap your mind around this...

Answer (score 0):

So if you wanted to sort by hours you would want to group the records. Here I'm using the built-in functions that return parts of a timestamp, `year()`, `month()`, `dayofmonth()`, `hour()`. Since you can't use an aggregate function in the `where` clause I had to use `having` to limit by the count requirement.

```
select date(create_date),
hour(create_date),
count(*) as surge from records
where create_date > curdate() - interval 1 day
group by year(create_date), month(create_date),
dayofmonth(create_date), hour(create_date)
having count(*) > 50;
```

Another method to accomplish your goal might be to `select` the `count` of records and `group by` the interval in question. In this case I'm adding an hour to the `create_date` to get your 1 hour suggested interval. Anytime the `count` is greater than 50 it returns a row. Notice I'm also `grouping by` the `hour`. This is to prevent multiple starts for a "surge" within the same hour:

```
select create_date,count(*) as surge from records
group by year(create_date), month(create_date),
dayofmonth(create_date),hour(create_date),
(create_date + interval 1 hour - create_date) having count(*) > 50;
```

The problem with this however is that some surges may last longer than 1 hour, but it should give you the moment the "surge" started.